# Custom authentication backend not called with Django rest?

Tags: firebase, django-rest-framework, firebase-authentication, django-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase for my django rest / nuxt project and I need to verify the id tokens after the user logs in - I only use Firebase for the auth part.

My custom auth class looks like this:

```
class FirebaseAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        print("Why is this never called")
        auth_header = request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

        if not auth_header:
            raise NoAuthToken("No auth token provided")

        id_token = auth_header.split(" ").pop()
        decoded_token = None
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        except Exception:
            raise InvalidAuthToken("Invalid auth token")
            pass

        if not id_token or not decoded_token:
            return None

        try:
            uid = decoded_token.get("uid")
        except Exception:
            raise FirebaseError()

        
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=uid)

        user.profile.last_activity = timezone.localtime()
        return (user, None)
```

And in my `settings.py` I got

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication",
    ),
}
```

`views.py`

```
@require_POST
def login_view(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    email = data.get("email")
    password = data.get("password")
    
    
    
    if email is None or password is None:
        return JsonResponse({"detail": "Please provide email and password."}, status=400)

    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    if user is None:
        return JsonResponse({"detail": "Invalid credentials."}, status=400)

    login(request, user)
    
    return JsonResponse({"detail": "Successfully logged in.", "isAuthenticated": True})
```

And on my nuxt app, the login:

```
async login() {
            this.error = null;
            try {
                const response = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password);
                const token = await response.user.getIdTokenResult();
                console.log(token.token);
                const res = await fetch("/account/login/", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { 
                        "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                        "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": token.token,
                        "X-CSRFToken": this.$store.getters.CSRFToken
                    },
                    credentials: "include",
                    mode: "cors",
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email: this.email, password: this.password }),
                });
                return await res.json()
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        },
```

I get a 200 everywhere - the user is logged in, both on firebase and on the django side of things, but the `FirebaseAuthentication` is not fired. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two steps

1. Obtain JWT token from Firebase
2. Authenticate the user by django REST (`"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"`) by obtained JWT token from step 1.

Login view is unnecessary here. You already did it from Frontend side.

Now you should do; just write class based view (prefer class based view to function based view).

**NB:** `authenticate` function will call `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` not `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` under `REST_FRAMEWORK` dict.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class SampleProtectedAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)  # Must include it to test user is authenticated 
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user) # will get user instance
```